# Openliberty login issue "The user is not granted access to any of the required roles"

Tags: java, security, open-liberty

or maybe someone can tell me what is wrong.

I am working on a small app..following this tutorial  : https://openliberty.io/guides/security-intro.html

Problem I get is :

```
Authorization failed for user bob while invoking ServletsJspExperiments on /admin. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [admin]
```

This is after I enter correct username and password in the login that is generated.

Here are the main problems..imo the problem is here somewhere:

My servlet

```
@FormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
        loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(errorPage = "/error.html",
                loginPage = "/login.html"))
@ServletSecurity(value = @HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = { "user", "admin" },
        transportGuarantee = ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL))
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside doGet AdminServlet");
        if (securityContext.isCallerInRole("admin")) {
//            resp.sendRedirect("/admin.jsf");
            resp.getWriter().println("You are in admin page");
        }
    }
}
```

My server.xml

```
 <featureManager>
        <feature>appSecurity-4.0</feature>

        <feature>servlet-5.0</feature>

        <!-- needed to run JSP examples -->
        <feature>pages-3.0</feature>

        <!-- needed to make JDBC calls -->
        <feature>jdbc-4.3</feature>

        <!-- for TLS -->
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

  ....

    <include location="userRegistry.xml"/>

    <webApplication location="ServletExperiments.war" contextRoot="${app.context.root}">

        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="admin">
                <user name="bob" />
            </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
    </webApplication>
```

userRegistry.xml file. (this is included from the server.xml)

```
<server description="Sample Liberty server">
    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="WebRealm">
        <user name="bob"
              password="{xor}PTA9Lyg7" /> <!-- bobpwd -->
    </basicRegistry>
</server>
```

My web.xml file...only the relevant parts

```
<!-- SECURITY ROLES -->
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AdminViewProperties</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**Update** ..added logs that appear when i try to do the login

```
[1/12/23, 17:13:20:637 EET] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.security.token.internal.TokenManagerImpl          I CWWKS4001I: The security token cannot be validated. This can be for the following reasons
1. The security token was generated on another server using different keys.
2. The token configuration or the security keys of the token service which created the token has been changed.
3. The token service which created the token is no longer available.
[1/12/23, 17:13:20:642 EET] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServiceImpl                   I CWWKS1652A: Authentication failed with status AuthStatus.SEND_CONTINUE for the web request /ServletsJspExperiments/admin. The user defined Java Authentication SPI for Containers (JASPIC) service null has determined that the authentication data is not valid.
[1/12/23, 17:13:25:136 EET] 0000003a com.ibm.ws.security.javaeesec.cdi.beans.Utils                I CWWKS1930I: The configured IdentityStore object was not found. If a user registry is configured, it will be used instead. If the IdentityStore object must be used, make sure that the IdentityStore object is configured properly.
[1/12/23, 17:13:25:170 EET] 0000003f y.authorization.builtin.internal.BuiltinAuthorizationService I CWWKS2104I: The authorization decision for resources in application ServletsJspExperiments will be made by using the group names of the user that matches the role names required to access that resource.
[1/12/23, 17:13:25:171 EET] 0000003f .ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl A CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user bob while invoking ServletsJspExperiments on /admin. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [admin].
```

Comment: Looks correct. Check out `messages.log` when your server starts up, maybe there is an initialization error. Also, if you change security settings I would suggest to do a clean restart of the server.

Comment: @Gas added some logs... I tried to address it by having the connection between user and role done via a group...still same logs appear...

Comment: It works, I rework original repo from jsf to plain jsp. Check this https://github.com/gasgithub/guide-security-intro . You can clone it and play with it.

Comment: @Gas i also took that repo, before your modifications and stripped it down..simplified it and it works...That is what bugs the hell out of me...what is the difference ? I also have my code on git...if you wanna try it out ...problably it won't work for you either : https://github.com/Testehan/ServletsJspExperiments

Comment: If the problem is with the token validation can you make sure that you clear your cookies or new/different browser and try so that we can make sure old tokens do not exist?

Comment: @Ajay tried with a different browser...same outcome

Comment: Found your issue ;-) see the answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found your issue :-)))

Your `pom.xml` file is inconsistent with `server.xml` file.
The pom file assumes that your app is called: `<artifactId>ServletsJspExperiments</artifactId>` but in the server.xml you are configuring app that is called: `location="ServletExperiments.war"`, and that is different, conflicting app. :-)

So to fix change this in your server.xml as follows (missing `Jsp` text):

```
<webApplication location="ServletJspExperiments.war" contextRoot="${app.context.root}">
```

Comment: the world of software development needs better errors IMO :)) I spent some time last night and basically copied all the code that you refactored into my project...and it still didn't work...Only when I created a new project did it work...i was thinking that there might be some path related issued or something...thx

Comment: For a problem like this you'll get something like:   [WARNING] CWWKM2179W: The application is not defined in the server configuration but the POM configuration indicates it should be installed in the apps folder. Application configuration is being added to the target server configuration dropins folder by the plug-in.

Comment: The liberty-maven-plugin will generate server config for you via a configDropins XML.  This allows you, in some cases to even skip the step of adding configuration in server.xml altogether (and avoiding the need to align/match the POM config).   But the downside, as noted, is that if your config doesn't match, like in this case, you get the CWWKM2179W message and we use our generated config instead.    Finally, it can also sometimes help to do a 'clean' if you are correcting or adjusting after the plugin generates config.

Comment: @ScottKurz yeah, that was the message :-) but in this case you have to provide custom config, as default doesnt have role bindings, which was the reason why app was not working I think.